# My cancelled flight caused me to overstay my visa and now my visa application was rejected

Tags: schengen, germany, schengen-visas, czech-republic, visa-rejections

I had a tourist visa to the Czech Republic for 2 weeks, my return plane ticket was the last day of my allocated visa.

2 days prior to me going back home, my Lufthansa flight got canceled and the earliest available alternative flight was 2 days later.

When connecting between the Czech Republic and Germany so that I can fly from there back home, I was taken aside and questioned since I overstayed my visa by 2 days.

Even though I clearly stated to the customs police that my flight was canceled with email proof from the airline, they marked my name on the system like I was some sort of illegal alien...

A few months pass and now I have applied for a new visa to the Czech Republic, and my visa now is rejected from the German side causing me to be technically banned from entering the Schengen area.

I have contacted the Czech embassy and they told me that they don't have a problem with me but Germany rejected me getting a visa because of what happened, and I was told to get this fixed and they will grant me a visa right away.

I have contacted Lufthansa to get an official email from them proving that they canceled my flight and no same-day alternatives were available.

I have also contacted the German consulate and they have taken my passport number mentioning that they will contact the German police about the issue.

My flight to the Czech Republic is in 7 days, the Czechs have told me they will provide me with a special visa request so that I can get it in time but for that, I need to get my name cleared in the coming days.

What can I do? Who can contact other than the parties I have mentioned? it's unacceptable that I'm being treated like an illegal alien even though im clearly innocent. Keeping in mind that I asked the German police when I was detained if this will cause issues with future visas, and they stated that it might if I want to come to Germany; but im my current case, I won't be visiting Germany, and it's not even part of the transit list on any of my flights for this trip.

Can this be fixed in a day or 2? Can I sue the airline for this? can I sue the German government for this?

I don't know what's possible and what I can do, I just want to catch my flight on time :(

Note:
All flights back to Lebanon were canceled on that day, this was due to the Lebanese government putting into action a new time zone out of nowhere which forced airlines to cancel trips so that they can adapt to the new timezone. https://apnews.com/article/lebanon-daylight-savings-time-9aee80838f6dfd53fd3564981f9667a8

In my communication with the German side, I clearly stated that I haven't gone through the proper protocol where I should've applied for a visa extension as soon as my flight was canceled due exclusively to my ignorance of the topic. And that this will not repeat itself.

I also stated in my email that my work, and family are back in Lebanon, and theres nothing for me to gain from a visa overstay.

UPDATE:

I was contacted again by the czech embassy mentioning that I still have an alert on SIS, I have forwarded this to the german consulate and now waiting their answer.

How long does this process take? is there any way i can get fined/imprisoned?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. The airline is not responsible for your visa status, and while this is obviously too late, you should have reached out to the police/immigration to arrange an emergency extension the day your flight was cancelled instead of just overstaying.

Comment: The lesson here is a) don’t book your return flight for the day your visa expires; and b) contact immigration immediately. Since you **did** overstay and did not follow the correct immigration procedure, I am not sure if you *can* clear your name

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147584/discussion-on-question-by-robin-geagea-my-cancelled-flight-caused-me-to-overstay); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 27):

Actually, you *did* overstay. Your best defense is that it was *negligent* rather than intentional, but you are responsible for reading the regulations. For the benefit of other readers of this Q&A:

**What to do when a flight is cancelled on the last day of a Schengen visa?**

You need to act on the day of the planned departure, because an expired Schengen visa cannot be extended. If you are not already at the airport, contact the immigration authorities at the place where you are staying.

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany) [Schengen - Visa - Extension](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324785/en/)

> A Schengen visa which **has already expired** cannot by extended.
> (emphasis by me)

[...]

> A visa extension can be considered for humanitarian or important personal reasons or in the case of force majeure.
>
> - Example of force majeure:
>   No air traffic due to weather conditions or strike

[...]

> Documents required
>
> - Passport with valid visa

Comment: Indeed, i wasn't familiar with the procedure and the protocols that should be followed when such a scenario happens.

Comment: Do you think if the german embassy contacts them directly with written proof from the airline stating that there were no alternative flights available, theres a chance i can get cleared quickly? @o.m.

Comment: @robingeagea no one can speculate on how quickly the authorities will clear this up. I wouldn't be surprised if it took German bureaucracy took a few weeks to move on this.

Comment: I have contacted the german embassy and consulate as soon as i got my rejection letter, they took my passport number and flight stamps directly mentioning that they will check with the german police about this, since its a diplomatic body doing the communication, would that typically make the process quicker? @Ozzy

Comment: @robingeagea, sorry, no idea how long this will take. The regular procedure when the visa is still valid is supposed to be on the same day, but now they might have to consult the Czechs.

Comment: @o.m. actually, the Czechs called me and apologized for the inconvenience mentioning that they granted me the visa but they cannot proceed with a refusal from Germany, they mentioned that as soon as this is fixed, they will let me apply for some sort of expedited visa application to get it quickly.
Based on what you said, i have hope

Comment: @robingeagea, the Czechs matter twice. You want a new visa from them, and you should have gone there to extend the old one while it was still valid.

Comment: @o.m. I have sent an email to the Federal Public Prosecutor General Office in Germany/ The german embassy/ The Czech embassy, is there any other party i should contact? Also thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @robingeagea *Do you think if the german embassy contacts them directly with written proof from the airline stating that there were no alternative flights available, theres a chance i can get cleared quickly?* You write a lot about this but it is in fact completely irrelevant. Playing devil's advocate, you could have bought a ticket from another airline, taken a bus to Ukraine, whatever. And even if none of this was realistically possible, the fact remains that you were present in the Schengen area after the end of your visa and legally responsible for that.

Comment: @Relaxed, to his benefit, the extension should have gove relatively smoothly if he had applied for one with these facts.

Comment: Your best arguments are that this was an honest mistake, that a ban is disproportionate for such a short overstay or not justified because you left quickly and voluntarily and do not present any serious risk of long overstay. But stop focusing on the details of the flight cancellation.

Comment: @Relaxed the reason why the plane was canceled was the fact that are flights to Lebanon were canceled on that date, basically during the month of Ramadan, the Lebanese government decided to not update the timing so that Muslims will have 1 hour of fasting. there were no alternative flights or airlines.

Comment: @Relaxed I agree with your statement, In my letter to the German Bureau, I had stated that it came to my knowledge that I could've applied for an extension and saved myself all this trouble, and the reason why this didn't happen was purely based on my ignorance, I also mentioned that my family and work are in Lebanon and that I go to Europe frequently for vacation thus the claim that Im a safety hazard or will probably overstay my visa again intensionally is baseless since I don't stand to gain anything from this.

Comment: @Relaxed Tomorrow I will hear back from the German Embassy, and if the outcome is positive, I will contact the Czech embassy directly to get started with my new visa application, I will post the outcome on this feed. 
What happened is a combination of ignorance on my end and a disproportionate assessment from the German side.

Comment: @robingeagea It may be worth posting your experience (what you did and what the outcome was) as an answer rather than in more comments. You could also use [chat] or post in [meta] if it's purely a "hey folks, I'm fine" follow-up.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Indeed, I will be posting it here as an answer, even if the outcome is negative, I will post what im told and if I receive any advice for whoever goes through this experience.

Comment: @Relaxed I heard back from the germans, my name is not banned and there is nothing that grants an automatic rejection, I was told this by the german embassy after they contacted the german police, I'm so lost as to what happened...

Comment: What would happen if e.g. while someone was en route to the airport, they were arrested because they happened to resemble someone who just robbed a bank, and although the police eventually determined that the resemblance was entirely coincidental and they were 100% innocent of the robbery or any other crime, they were not released until after their visa had expired?  Would someone in such circumstance be expected--or even able--to make arrangements to extend their visa while they were detained?

Comment: @supercat, I don't know anybody who got into such a scenario, and neither did it make the headlines recently. My advice for any victim of such circumstances would be to ask the criminal police for a written confirmation before starting to arrange the replacement flight. And to consult a lawyer for specific remedies ...